# How to direct Android Devs on SO to the Android Enthusiast's Beta Site?

Tags: support, status-completed, beta-phase, android, ask-different

The Android Exchange Beta is trying to appeal to a wider audience, including Android Devs who may have Q&A that is well-suited for a community of Android users (i.e. UI questions, beta-testing opportunities, etc.). And in general, Android Devs may glean useful info from the Q&A already going on there.

This question could also apply to the Apple Stack Exchange site. 
Thanks in advance for the feedback.

**EDIT:** This suggestion has been implemented! See answer below. Can a mod tag it as status-completed?

Comment: I would love to see this.  There are often questions on SO that really belong on Android.SE (I'm sure the same for Apple)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** The request has been completed! Here is an updated screen shot when you search the Android tag:

[image]

And when you click the about:

[image]

<s>A simple idea would be to add a link on the Android Tag page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) (shown below). This space is for Sponsored Links so perhaps there could be a section beneath it, such as "Other Stack Exchange sites for this tag" or simply include the link under Sponsored Links.</s>

---

[image]